# Why the explicit template instantiation doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates

Could you please explain, why the explicit template instantiation doesn't work here?

```
template <typename T>
bool IsEqual(T v1, T v2) {
    return v1 == v2;
}

template bool IsEqual<double>(double a, double b);

int main() {  
    int c = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    IsEqual(c,d)
    return 0;
}
```

The error the code produces is:

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int' and 'double')
```

If the function isn't a template function then everything works well. So I expect an explicit instantiation to create the same function.

```
bool IsEqualT (double a, double b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Comment: because `c` is a `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit template instantiation guarantees that the compiler produces code for a particular set of template parameters, which means it will be found if the linker needs it.

It doesn't hide other combinations of template parameters, or prevent them from being instantiated (implicitly or otherwise).

As such, explicit instantiation has no effect on template parameter deduction, and no effect on overload resolution.  The whole family of possible instantiation are still candidates.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you explain, why does `IsEqual<double>(c,d);` work? It appears to me that it creates the same template instantiation as `template bool IsEqual<double>(double a, double b);`.

Comment: @Konstantin: More importantly, it tells the compiler which overload to use (skipping deduction).  The compiler never had any problem with doing the instantiation of `IsEqual<double>`, it simply couldn't figure out which instantiation that function call used.

Comment: Thank you very much again for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Template parameter deduction doesnt take care about explicit instantiation or overload resolution.

You have to pass arguments of same type if you want to call `IsEqual` or change its declaration to

```
template <typename T, typename S>
bool IsEqual(T v1, S v2) {
    return v1 == v2;
}

// ... main

int c = 4;
double d = 4.0;
printf("%s", IsEqual(c,d) == true ? "True" : "False"); // Prints true
```

or help compiler choose right overload by specifing `T` as `double`.

```
IsEqual<double>(c,d);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Could you please explain why the function `bool IsEqualT (double a, double b)` isn't created by the explicit instantiation?

Comment: @Konstantin: It *is* created by the explicit instantiation.  But overload resolution doesn't give stronger preference to functions created from explicit template instantiation over implicit instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

Manually stamping out

```
template bool IsEqual<double>(double a, double b)
```

Doesn't stop the compiler from doing template argument deduction in

```
IsEqual(c,d)
```

It just tells the compiler regardless of what other functions it might stamp out, you want it to stamp out that function for `double`s.

So, since you still go through template argument deduction, and `int` is not the same as `double` you get the compiler error.  You will either have to cast `c` to a double or rewrite the function to have 2 template parameters so it can take two different types.